# How to add string to unicode without errors popped by unicode escape?

Tags: python-unicode, unicode-string, unicode-escapes

Here is basically what i want to do:

```
unicode_string = "366d"
unicode_string_with_u = u"\u%s" % (unicode_string)
```

and it gives:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

I have an iteration that generates strings like the `unicode_string = "366d"` above, and want to change each of the four-digit number into something look like `u"\u366d"` so that it will print the unicode character I want: `㙭` . As a result of the iteration, it will give me a string look like `㞘䗳駯獦蕄倢`
------ So how can I deal with this problem with core python and python import modules only?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting your four-digit hex value into a Unicode string (`u`), insert it into a byte string (`b`) and then decode the whole thing using the [built-in `unicode_escape` text encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings):

```
>>> unicode_string = "366d"
>>> u"\u%s" % (unicode_string)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape
>>> b"\u%s" % (unicode_string)
'\\u366d'
>>> (b"\u%s" % (unicode_string)).decode("unicode_escape")
u'\u366d'
>>> print(_)
㙭
```

It looks like something internally is trying to parse the string literal in your code using `unicode_decode`. That is, it's literally trying to parse the characters `\u%s`, which is not a valid Unicode escape sequence.